# Tag-it not working on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsfiddle, tag-it

```js
$("#fruitTags").tagit();
```

```html
<input id="fruitTags" placeholder="Enter Your Fruit Tags" ></input>
```

I am trying to get my tag-it setup working on jsfiddle. I have replicated this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3HDh/49/

I cannot figure out why my version (https://jsfiddle.net/7fuho9eu/3/) is not working. Here is my code:

I've added the following resources:

- http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/js/tag-it.js
- http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/css/jquery.tagit.css
- http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/css/tagit.ui-zendesk.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your link uses https, my friend. 
When the connection is secure there tend to be some resource inclusion problems.

As you can see the reference link you've provided has a http:// link and yours is with an s

Hope this helped.

Cheers!!

Comment: NP @GokulPrasad. This question was a precursor to the real issue I am dealing with. Any chance you might have an idea on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49711415/tag-it-ul-li-field-not-validating-correctly?noredirect=1#comment86436514_49711415?  Tx.